# Batch Script: Export last git commit message to a variable

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I'm trying to assign the last commit message inside a git repository to a variable in a windows batch script and then export the variable. From a lot of questions from StackOverflow, it seems that the command should be:

```
for /f "Tokens=2" %a in ('git log -1 --pretty=%B') do @set commit_message=%a

export %commit_message%
```

But it's giving the following error.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '%B': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

In Linux it is quite straight forward. Only `export commit_message=$(git log -1 --pretty=%B)`.

Comment: Double all your percent symbols.

Comment: This question is specifically tagged batch-file therefore try either, `... %%X In ('git log -1 --pretty^=%%B') Do @Set "commit_message=%%X"` or `... %%X In ('"git log -1 --pretty=%%B"') Do @Set "commit_message=%%X"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't parse the git command directly. This worked on my site:

```
@echo off
git log -1 --pretty=%%B > %temp%\git.txt
for /f "Tokens=*" %%a in (%temp%\git.txt) do @set commit_message=%%a

echo %commit_message%
::export %commit_message%
```

Note the doubled '%'. I'm not sure about that export command. I've never seen this. Maybe `setx` is what you need?

Comment: `set` is fine as I'm using the variable value in the same script. `setx` sets the variables to be used by future spawned cmd's not the current one. Thanks for your help.